# SQL group and summing at new row

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I have an issue where I am trying to create a new "row" (not part of the database) where it only gives me the SUM of the "count" column. I am wondering if that is possible?

I tried adding the SUM(count(cost) as "total product cost" OVER() AS Total_Count; but that just creates a new column with the summed amount of 550.00 displayed in each row. I want that 550.00 to be at the bottom as the final count of that column.

```
select product, count(cost) as 'total product cost'

from product_Table

where product_Tier = 'grocery'

and as_of_date = '8/13/2020'

Group By product

Results:

product   total product cost
corn       250.00
tomatoes   300.00
SUM        550.00          <--trying to create a row like this.
```

Comment: see `ROLLUP` on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) page

Comment: to get the text `SUM` on your total-line use [ISNULL()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most databases support the standard `grouping sets` functionality:

```
select coalesce(product, 'Total'), count(cost) as totalproductcost
from product_Table
where product_Tier = 'grocery' and
      as_of_date = '2020-08-13'
group by grouping sets ( product, () );
```

Some databases support `rollup` but not `grouping sets`.  The syntax might vary, but something like:

```
select coalesce(product, 'Total'), count(cost) as totalproductcost
from product_Table
where product_Tier = 'grocery' and
      as_of_date = '2020-08-13'
group by product with rollup;
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. Both works great. However, in my select statement I entered 2 more functions, Max (cost, and Min (cost) which shows the max and min of each product. However, the rollup / grouping sets also inputted numerical values in the bottom where the extra row was created. With your experience, is there a way to manipulate those numbers at the bottom? Been googling around but seems hard to dig a solution without experience.

Comment: @JasonTodd . . . You might want to ask a new question with sample data and desired results.  However, the "total" row is going to have the same columns as all other rows.  You can use a `case` expression to manipulate the logic, possibly.

Answer (score 0):

```
select product, count(cost) as 'total product cost'
from product_Table
where product_Tier = 'grocery'
  and as_of_date = '8/13/2020'
Group By product
union 
select product,sum(cost)
from product_Table
where product_Tier = 'grocery'
  and as_of_date = '8/13/2020'
Group By product;
```